How to implement threshold for JUnit tests
I have Junit tests which is invoked by a test class which is called TestRunner and look like this:
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class TestRunner {

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{index} {0}")
    void test(String query, TestCase testCase) throws IOException {
        //do something
   }
}

Junit version 5.x.x
I need to implement some threshold which should works in the next way:
Threshold 90%
Means if I have 10 Junit tests and 1 of them is failed it should not lead to build failing and tests should be considered as passed.
In case if less than 90% tests is passed build should failed.
I've tried to use TestWatcher and added it with
@ExtendWith(TestResultWatcher.class) 

which is help me to count how many tests are passed and failed, but still if one of tests are failing it always lead to build failing.
How can this be bypassed and cause the build to fail only if the threshold of passed tests is below a specified value?

"I need to implement some threshold which should works in the next way: Threshold 90% Means if I have 10 Junit tests and 1 of them is failed it should not lead to build failing and tests should be considered as passed." - This feels very, very wrong. A failing test indicates a problem. Why would you ignore it?

I know about that, but it is specific case and customers want exactly such logic. For them it’s okay that some part of tests can failed.

I need to explain a little that the tests do not check the code logic, but the interaction with a third-party service that works very similar to the AI chat bot.
And the point is that there are test scripts that supposedly come from the user and a certain response is generated by a third-party service.
This is why it is normal for customers if only 90 percent of tests pass

Tests are there for you as the author of code, fixer of bugs, maintainer of functionality. They are not there for the customer, so: it isn't really important what the customer thinks about tests. The customer might also think it isn't important to plan a project, or to use an issue tracker, or to have a deployment script, or dozens of other things which actually are important in software engineering. It's always better to find a bug from tests than from a live user discovering it for you.

Only one thing is matter now. It's possible or not. If you have some ideas it would be great if you can share with me.

If you're using Gradle or Surefire to run JUnit, you can not do this. JUnit doesn't fail your build, Gradle or Surefire do. What you can do is launch JUnit with the Launcher API, then look at the results and decide to fail the build based on those results. You can do this by invoking the launcher api from a main method. See: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api
